# Calling mongoose model method after passing it as a function argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to call a method of a mongoose model in a function after passing it as an argument and it's not working, this is the full function:

```
function isIdTaken(model,id){
    model.countDocuments({_id: id}, function(err,count){
        if(!err){
            if(count > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

The function call itself is `isIdTaken(Poll,id);` where Poll is a model compiled and imported from an external javascript file.
When I try to call it I get an error that `model.countDocuments is not a function`.

The model is supposed to be a constructor, from mongoose documentation, and the same method `.countDocuments(query, callback)` works if the model is not passed as argument to a function.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong by chance?

Edit. Full function invocation:

```
app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    let id = generateId();
    while(isIdTaken(Poll, id)){
        id = generateId();
    }
    Poll.create({_id: id}, (err)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.redirect(`/polls/${id}`);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Please post your `countDocuments` method definition and declaration.

Comment: @Mahan https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.countDocuments from Mongoose documentation

Comment: Post your code where call isIdTaken function and do you correctly import your model?
The better way is to import your model instead of passing it through function parameter.

Comment: I do import the model correctly: as I wrote in the last paragraph of the original question if I don't pass the model as an argument to the function and just call the method it works fine. I would like to understand why it's not working because it would be useful to make middleware that is not bound to a single model.
The function invocation is in a post route: I'll add it at the end of the main question since I can't format properly here.